# Axios status is 449 despite response being 200

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have an endpoint `/sales/internalorders/5` which returns `200` when I open it directly in a browser/curl/etc. It's correctly returning as `application/json`.

The endpoint is provided by Laravel, which provides the data from a controller as:

```php
return response()->json(['data' => $return], 200);
```

I'm calling it in the `mounted()` hook of my Vue component:

```js
axios.get('admin/sales/internalorders/'+this.$route.params.id)
    .then((response) => {console.log(response)})
    .catch(error=>{console.log(error)})
```

While `response.request.status` is 200, `response.status` is returning `449` and `response.data` is unset:

[image: Screenshot of console showing response]

**Edited** to state that the data is being prepared by Laravel

Comment: You're gonna have to give us some more info on the server-side component of all this. Vue/Axios aren't setting the 449 response, your API/server is.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz - I've edited to show that it's being returned by Laravel. If it's the case that it's the server-side at issue, isn't it odd that opening the endpoint directly gives a 200?

Comment: I've never had Laravel return a 449 without custom code; the "Unfortunately we cannot find a..." in your `responseText` looks like you're constructing some sort of custom error handling.

Comment: That's in the data which is being returned by the endpoint, rather than the response object attributes. The endpoint fetches an internal url and proxies the response to the web.

Comment: @ceejayoz you were on the right track - there was a response macro we should have been using instead of `response()->json()` _and_ Axios had been overrridden!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that Axios had been overridden *and* there was a custom Laravel response macro we should have been using.

This was apparently so that error messages could be standardised across the app

Thanks to @ceejayoz, who was on the right track!